# Inno Setup: how to make a change option on "Uninstall or change a program"

Tags: installation, inno-setup

On "Uninstall or change a program" on windows, some of the programs have a change option when you right click on them. 
[image] 
How can I add a change option to my program through Inno Setup?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but have you tried using [components](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the [`AppModifyPath`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmodifypath) directive. The reference describes it as:

> When this directive is set, a separate "Modify" button in the
>   Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet will be displayed.